# Can't remove a directory

Tags: ubuntu, unix, shell

I'm trying this:

```
rm -fr /app/foo
```

But getting error message:

```
rm: cannot remove `/app/foo': Is a directory
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Try `rmdir /app/foo`

Comment: @Ashtray, 'rmdir: failed to remove `/app/foo': No such file or directory'. Weirdo.

Comment: Do you remember how you created it? Maybe the slashes are actual special characters in filename?

Comment: @Ashtray, it's created by a build script (written not by me). How can I check that?

Comment: `mkdir app && mkdir app/foo && rm -fr app/foo && rm -fr app` just works for me, so there is something else going on. We need to know more. Rights, symbolic links etc... (ls -ltr ?)

Comment: Please post the output of `ls -ltr /app | grep foo`, `type rm` and `ls -l /app/foo`.

Comment: Does that directory happen to be a mount point for something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error hints at the directory being a mount point.

Unmount whatever is there:

```
umount /app/foo
```

Then, try to remove the directory again.